# how to return a collection

Tags: java, android

I would like to return this collection but it is giving me an error:

```
public Collection<String> Shuffle()

{
return   Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(FullDeck));
}
```

FullDeck is an String array

Comment: there is no way that its related to android i guess

Comment: What is `FullDeck` and what do you want to return?

Comment: Which error is given?

Comment: return type of Collections.shuffle() is void so after shuffling you have to return FullDeck

Comment: Do you want the backing FullDeck array to be modified?

Comment: Right. It is different if you want to shuffle the original list or you need a copy

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Do you know that `Arrays.asList(FullDeck)` doesn't create copy of used array so `Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(FullDeck))` will not shuffle new collection with elements from `FullDeck` but `FullDeck` itself? Returning List which is wrapping FullDeck is kind of pointless, because `Collection<String> deck1 = shuffle(); Collection<String> deck2 = shuffle();` would be different lists but with exactly same content. Did you maybe wanted to create `newShuffledDeck()` method which would return collection which elements from `FullDeck` but which has its own order?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`Collections.shuffle()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle%28java.util.List%29) doesn't return anything. You would have to do:

```
public Collection<String> shuffle() {
    List<String> list = Arrays.asList(FullDeck);
    Collections.shuffle(list);
    return list;
}
```

Note that, as @Seelenvirtuose points out, the `shuffle()` operation will change the underlying array as well. That means that you could just let your `shuffle()` method have a `void` method type, and access the `FullDeck` array directly afterwards. This would let you shorten this method to a single line: `Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(FullDeck));`

Comment: Your edited answer is better.. :)

Comment: I want to limit the amount of code and just user the return statement... can yo do that in one return statement?

Comment: No, there is no way to shorten these statements. You would have to find/write an alternative shuffle method with a return type.

Comment: The method `Arrays.asList` will return a _wrapping list_ for the provided array. Each read and write operation is in fact passed through to the underlying array. This effectively eliminates the need to return a list. A _void_ method that simply shuffles the deck would be better because the `FullDeck` field will always reflect the shuffling after the method call, anyway. Maybe you should edit your answer and add this as a note.

Answer (score 3):

The [shuffle()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle%28java.util.List%29) method returns `void`, so you don't need a return value. You can rewrite the code as follow. Note that this method as the side effect to alter the original `FullDeck` list.

```
public void shuffle()
{
    Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(fullDeck));
}
```

Please also note that methods and variables in Java should start with lowercase letters.

Comment: Maybe you should add a note that this indeed effects the content of the `FullDeck` field (which maybe is exactly what the OP wants).

Answer (score 0):

`Collection.shuffle()` does not return anything. Rather it modifies the argument list. Read the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle%28java.util.List%29) here.

Rather use this:

```
    List<String> list = Arrays.asList(FullDeck);
    // Shuffle the list
    Collections.shuffle(list);
    return list;
```

Answer (score -3):

You're much better off returning just a plain old List, or better yet, a Collection, like this:

```
// after: method returns a Collection reference
private Collection getList()
{
  Collection list = new LinkedList();
  list.add("Hello");
  list.add("world");
  return list;
}
```

Comment: I want to limit the amount of code and just user the return statement... can yo do that in one return statement?