# Why should I use shuffle to return a list on return value collection? (Java)

Tags: java, collections

I have Collection as a return value for a method, so I thought I would simply use ArrayList and return the ArrayList. Now I've seen on the Internet that someone thinks that before returning the ArrayList, if the return value is Collection, you should do Collections.shuffle(ArrayList) first. Why? What is the purpose? Can't you just return the ArrayList directly?

Comment: Could you add the source where you've seen that?

Comment: Yes. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24491067/how-to-return-a-collection

Comment: He said to him he have to use Collections.shuffle, because: "Collections.shuffle() doesn't return anything. You would have to do", but why I should use shuffle and not only return the list?

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding it... In that case the user wanted to shuffle the collection so the answer was specific to the question and example posted there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24491067/how-to-return-a-collection) you are referring to does not suggest that you *should* shuffle a collection before you return it. From the naming there ("FullDeck") I would guess that it is something related to a card deck that should be shuffled for a game.

You don't need to shuffle an `ArrayList` before you return it as a collection, you can directly return the list - it implements the `Collection` interface and doesn't need any further processing to be accessed by that interface.

The shuffling is only relevant if you want to have the elements of the list in random order for some other reason.

Comment: To add;  you should try to return as the interface closest in relation to how it will be used.  If the collection will just be iterated, then returning as a collection is fine. However, if you might use any of the methods from List, you should return a List.  Personally, I would return the List.

Comment: No, be as coarse as possible with things you return from your code (or accept as parameters). If there is not reason for a `List`, don't use it (yet). When you change code later, you loose flexibility: if you later find out, a `Set` would be more appropriate internally, you would have to copy that into a list interface. If you only expose a `Collection` in the beginning, that change does not interfere with the consumer of your method.

Comment: No.  A List *IS* a Collection; List extends Collection.  You lose nothing by returning a List and you gain nothing by returning a Collection.